# simplify svg (remove viewBox attribute) to obtain pure svg path

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to write some svgs on pdf file at precise position using javascript.
My webapp let the users make their drawings then I crop these drawings to remove unused white space and save them on a pdf.
Cropping svg adds viewBox attribute which isn't supported by the majority of js pdf library available.
This means that position and scale factor are wrong!
So my attempt to solve the problem was simplify the svg before put it on pdf file.
As far as I know there are few utils that could do this task:

- svgcleaner
- svgo
- scour

Unfortunately none of them completely remove viewbox attribute.
Consider that this task should be completely automated so using programs like inkscape or Adobe Illustrator is not a possible solution.

Comment: The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers: min-x, min-y, width and height. If min-x = min-y = 0 you can use the other 2 numbers as the width and the height of the svg element. However when you are cropping the svg element the min-x & min-y won't be 0. This means that you will need to wrap everything in a group and translate the group in the opposite direction: - min-x & - min-y

Comment: This seems to be my only option! Wrap everything in a group and Hope that svgcleaner or svgo Could remove trasform attribute re calculating correctly path coordinates...

Comment: If you have a path you can first convert the d attribute to [all relative commands](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv) and instead of translating you can change the first move-to (M) values, thus recalculating the path

Comment: Interesting, thanks @enxaneta! I saw the codepen sample but I didn't understand exactly how it works. Could you give me some explanation please? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented:

The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers: min-x, min-y, width and height. If min-x = min-y = 0 you can use the other 2 numbers as the width and the height of the svg element. However when you are cropping the svg element the min-x & min-y won't be 0. This means that you will need to wrap everything in a group and translate the group in the opposite direction: - min-x & - min-y.

Alternatively you can first convert the d attribute to all relative commands and instead of translating you can change the first move-to (M) values, thus recalculating the path.

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
// get the viewBox of the original svg element and split it by space or commas
let vb = original.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/[ ,]+/);
//console.log(vb); // ["103", "118", "94", "83"]

//set the width and the height of the copy
copy.setAttribute("width",vb[2]);
copy.setAttribute("height",vb[3]);

// get the d attribute of the original
let path = document.querySelector("#original path").getAttribute("d");

let pathRel = Snap.path.toRelative(path);
//console.log(pathRel)
//change the coords of the first move to command
pathRel[0][1] -= vb[0];
pathRel[0][2] -= vb[1];

//a variable to be used as the d attribute for the copy path
let d = ""  
pathRel.forEach(p=>{d+=(p.join(" "))})
//console.log(d)
//set the d attribute of the copy path
document.querySelector("#copy path").setAttribute("d",d)
```

```css
#original{width:94px;}
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg.js"></script>

<svg id="original" viewBox="103 118 94 83"><path d="M144.974,122.645Q150,114,155.026,122.645L194.974,191.355Q200,200,190,200L110,200Q100,200,105.026,191.355Z"></path></svg>


<svg id="copy" ><path></path></svg>
```